# Handling complex types in PHP/WSDL

Tags: php, wsdl

I have been using perl and mySql for just over a day and have written a basic web service PHP client/server that queries a database and returns the results to the client. I have some experience using java web services and JAX-WS.

Due to the lack of typing the handling of complex types is quite different than in JAX-WS in that no type validation is done on the return or input parameter. The server returns a multi dimensional array to the client and all works correctly.

While playing around with the WSDL I noticed that the type declarations have no affect, despite being referenced in the part element of the message element. I deleted the entire types declaration and the program continued to work correctly.

Am I missing something, is there anyway in PHP to use the WSDL to enforce the web service contract?

**------- client ---------**

```
<?php
// turn off the WSDL cache
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/~someuser/apams/apams.wsdl");

$fID = 1;

$franchises = $client->getFranchises($fID);
$rid= $franchises["Franchises"][1]["Id"];
$rdesc= $franchises["Franchises"][1]["Description"];

print("The id: $rid\n");
print("The description: $rdesc\n");

?>
```

**--------- server -------------**

```
<?php
function getFranchises($pfID) 
{
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbtest where franchiseID=$pfID");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $rID=$row['franchiseID'];
  $rDesc=$row['franchisedDescription'];
  }
mysql_close($con);
  return array("Franchises" =>  array(1=> array("Id"=>$rID, "Description"=>$rDesc)) );
}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$server = new SoapServer('apams.wsdl');

$server->addFunction("getFranchises");

$con =mysql_connect("localhost","testuser","******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected=mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use testdb : ' . mysql_error());
}

$server->handle();
?>
```

Comment: WSDL is too big to post but the part elements refer to the complex type
`<message name='getFranchisesRequest'> 
  <part name='symbol' type='xsd:string'/> 
</message> 
<message name='getFranchisesResponse'> 
  <part name='FranchisesResponse' type='tns:FranchisesResponse'/> 
</message>`
If I remove the complex type FranchiseResponse the service continues to work as normal.

Comment: Hi! You can format your code by putting 4 spaces before each line *(The `{}` button on top of the editor does just that)* -- I've done it for you this time :-) ;; see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more informations on how you can format your posts.